# Is $f_n(x) $ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ ?.

Tags: real-analysis

Is  $f_n(x)  = \sqrt [2n]{1+ x^{2n} }$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

My attempts:  No, $\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = \max (1, |x^{2n}|) = f(x),$ as  I know  that $f(x) =x^2$  is  not U.C. on $\mathbb{R}$

Is it true ?

Comment: is it a general fact that uniform limit of continuous functions is uniformly continuous? what about uniform limit of uniformly continuous functions being uniformly continuous? I think both answers are "no".

Comment: There's something wrong with your evaluation of $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$, because the expression you've suggested depends on $n$. In fact, the limiting function will be uniformly continuous (not that it really matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is uniformly convergent.

First, point-wise limit is $$f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x) = \max\{1,|x|\}$$
Let's then calculate $||f_n-f|| = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$. Let's consider separately $|x|<1$ and $|x|\ge 1$.

For $|x|<1$ we have 
$$ \sup_{|x|<1}|f_n(x)-f(x)| = \sup_{|x|<1}\big(\sqrt[2n]{1+x^{2n}} - 1\big) = \sqrt[2n]{2} - 1 $$

For $|x|\ge 1$ we have
\begin{align} |f_n(x)-f(x)| &= \sqrt[2n]{1+x^{2n}} - |x| = \\
&= |x| (\sqrt[2n]{1+x^{-2n}} - 1) \le |x| \cdot \frac{1}{2n}|x|^{-2n}  \end{align}
where the last inequality comes from the Bernoulli's inequality. We have then
$$ \sup_{|x|\ge 1} |f_n(x)-f(x)| \le \sup_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{|x|^{1-2n}}{2n} = \frac{1}{2n}$$

We have then:
$$ ||f_n-f|| \le \max\{\sqrt[2n]{2} - 1,\frac{1}{2n}\} \rightarrow^{n\rightarrow \infty} 0$$
So sequence $f_n$ is uniformly convergent.